# Particle mesh Ewald: recommended splitting into short and long range

Tags: poisson, fourier-transform, partitioning

[Particle mesh Ewald](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ewald_summation#Particle_mesh_Ewald_.28PME.29_method)  method for acceleration of solving pairwise interaction by long range forces (electrostatic, gravitational ... ) seem to be very general and easy to implement. The basic principle is well described in many sources.

What is harder to find is how exactly split the potential kernel ( say $V(r)=1/r = V_{SR}(r) + V_{LR}$ ) into short range and long range part. In other words:

- How should I choose short range part $V_{SR}(r)$ so that the long
  range part $V_{LR} = V(r) - V_{SR}(r)$ is easy to express in Fourier
  space as some analytic function fast to evaluate numerically.
- It would be nice to use similar splitting in all dimension ( 1D, 2D, 3D ).

e.g. somewhere I read that often is used [Yukawa-like potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_potential) 
 $V_{SR} = \exp(-\beta r )/r$ or Gaussian like damping $V_{SR} = \exp(-\beta r^2 )/r$.

But how to evaluate Fourier transform of long range $V_{LR}(r)$ efficintly in such case? Or is there any better choice of $V_{SR}$.

Answer (score 1):

Check out:

Nijboer, B. R. A., & De Wette, F. W. (1957). On the calculation of lattice sums. Physica, 23(1-5), 309–321. [doi:10.1016/S0031-8914(57)92124-9](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0031-8914(57)92124-9)

There they make the case for using a splitting based on the *incomplete Gamma function*.  That splitting generalizes the choice of the *error function* to arbitrary dimensions.